# Cannot create database with terminal doctrine:database:create

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I cannot succeed in creating a database with Symfony throught the terminal

*(I use a MAC and MAMP)*

**The line in the Terminal**

```
MacBook-Pro-de-XXX:Symfony XXX$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

**The answer I got in Terminal**

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 40

Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=52773 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 40

Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

**Here some other information that might help you help me to find where the probleme come from**

the parameters.yml file in Symfony/app/config

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost:8888
database_port: null
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: root
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

modify your host. if you have running mySql service on port 8888 your configuration should be as

```
    database_host: localhost 
    database_port: 8888
```

if your mysql running on default port, use below configuration

```
    database_host: localhost 
    database_port: null
```

hope this helps.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: but now when using the following: doctinge:schema:update --dump-sql I got the following: Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' ... I don't undersand because all the php.ini field I have the following date.timezone: "Europe/Berlin"

Comment: You most likely have multiple php.ini files... http://www.epicfoobar.com/2013/10/how-to-set-time-zone-in-symfony2/ shows some more ways to set the timezone directly in the app

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the MySQL server is actually running. Also the MAMP default port for MySQL is 3306 and not 8888.

```
database_host: localhost
database_port: 3306
```